# Image not displayed in chrome and firefox using "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader"

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader" to display iamge in div

My code is:

```
<body class="style_page" style="margin: 0px; background: white;" onload="onLoad()"
onunload="onUnload()" onresize="onResize()">
<div id="mediaPlayer" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
</div>
<div id="first" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0px; width: 800px; height: 600px;
    font-size: 10pt; background: white;">
    <div class="placeholder" style="left: 0%; top: 0%; width: 100%; height: 166%;">
        <div class="outline" style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=scale, src='output6.jpg');">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works fine in IE8 but doesn't work in Mozilla and google chrome

Plz help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla, Opera, G.Chrome and other browsers doesn't support Microsoft filters for transform text and images(controls). I think that every brower producer use diferent method.
Try to find help on their sites, and you must write javascript functions to recognize browser whos load page you developed.